# AsParallel() - with more than 2 threads in parallel in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have a method that I call 8 times with different parametres.
I use

```
 AvailableYears.AsParallel()
             .Select<Int32,DateUsedByThread>(x => GetDataForYearWorker(x,CIF))
             .ToList();
```

GetDataForYearWorker gets the response from a webservice synchronously. It uses very little computing power on my asp.net application, but it ussualy takes 3-5 sec for each webservice response. Because the calls to the webservice are independent of eachother, I want to make tham all at the same time. But it looks like only 2 threads can run at the same time. Why is this and how can I have 8 threads working at the same time?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

By default `.AsParallel()` will spin up one thread per core on the machine running the query. If you wish to alter this behavior look at [WithDegreeOfParallelism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.withdegreeofparallelism).

```
AvailableYears.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(5)
             .Select<Int32,DateUsedByThread>(x => GetDataForYearWorker(x,CIF))
             .ToList();
```